# How to pass to axios a Vuex variable using Nuxt.js?

Tags: axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I actually using Axios in a Nuxt.js project to catch Json file to display it on my website. I would like to use a variable store in Vuex to select the path for my Axios get request.

Here's what my `<script>` looks like:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import vuex from 'vuex'

export default {

  async asyncData({ }) {
    const json = await axios.get(`https://myurl.com/${$store.getters["getPath"]}`)
    return { json }
  }
}
</script>
```

Pretty sure that isn't the good method to do it. I receive the console error : `ReferenceError: store is not defined`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the `asyncData` method you don't have access to `this` keyword so the `asyncData` method receives the `context` object as an argument from which you can get access to Axios, Vuex etc. And thus you don't need to import Axios and Vuex.

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios, store }) { //here we get Axios and Vuex
    const json = await $axios.get(`https://myurl.com/${store.getters["getPath"]}`)
    return { json }
  }
}
```